# How to cut from one position to another , if 2 positions having a match in unix

Tags: unix, sed, grep, solaris, cut

I have a file like this

```
ABCDEFGH  
IJKLMNOP
QRSTUFWH
```

if 6th position = F and if 8th position = H
I want to cut from position 2 to 4

So the output should be

```
BCD
RST
```

I can take records with the matching pattern to another file using this -

```
grep  '^.....F.H' f1.txt > f2.txt
```

What i want is only position 2 to 4 , which matches the pattern.
Please help
Thank you

Comment: It is always a good practice to mention your O.S details too, like which O.S you are testing commands. Please do add this in your posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk 'substr($0,6,1)=="F" && substr($0,8,1)=="H"{print substr($0,2,3)}' Input_file
```

Since you added Solaris tag in your question try changing `awk` to `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk` in case you are on Solaris.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -En 's/^.(...).F.H.*/\1/p' file
```

Pattern match and use grouping and back reference to extract the required string.

Answer (score 1):

This POSIX `awk` should work on most system:

```
awk '$6=="F" && $8=="H" {print $2$3$4}' FS="" file
BCD
RST
```

By setting Field Separator to nothing, every character becomes one field, so just test field 6 and 8, and then print field 2-4.

Comment: You should mention that that's relying on undefined behavior per POSIX. Different awks will do different things when FS is null.